# run js file in function of my current_page

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to run my script from js file in function of my current_page

To do that i'm trying something like that

**Step 1**
 ( insert a params (idz = 1 || 2) into my href to use it latter)

*groups/show.html.erb*

```
 <%- if current_page?("/groups/#{task.group.id}/")%>
  <a href="/tasks/<%=task.id%>/undone?idz='1'" data-method="patch" data-remote="true" class="task_done_btn">undone</a>
<% elsif current_page?("/groups/#{task.group.id}/task_board") %>
  <a href="/tasks/<%=task.id%>/undone?idz='2'" data-method="patch" data-remote="true" class="task_done_btn">undone</a>
<% end %>
```

**Step 2** (transfert the idz defined in the first step into a local variable)

*controllers/tasks_controller.rb*

```
def undone
  respond_to do |format|
    @idz = idz
    format.html { redirect_back}
    format.js 
  end
end
```

**Step 3** (use the idz as a condition to run my jquery)

*tasks/undone.js.erb*

```
<%- if @idz == 1 %>
  // jquery 1
<% elsif @idz == 2 %>
  // jquery 2
<% end %>
```

But this method is'nt working (--). Do you know how I can solve that ? I think the problem append into the step2, when I want to attribute the number of my params(idz) into a local variable

Comment: You should do `@idz = params[:idz]`

Comment: Thanks for your answer @7urkm3n, I've finally succeed it, but is not an elegant solution at the end. So i'm trying to remake entirely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see, you are using `remote: true`

**show.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to "undone", undone_task_path(task.id, :idz=> "1"), class: "task_done_btn", remote: true %>
```

**Controller**

```
def undone
  respond_to do |format|
    @idz = params[:idz]
    #no need format.html, because using remote: true
    format.js 
  end
end
```

**routes**

```
resources :tasks do
  member do
    put 'undone'
  end
end
```

**undone.js.erb**

```
<%- if @idz == 1 %>
  // jquery 1
<% else %> #no need elsif
  // jquery 2
<% end %>
```